# my daemon docker container doesn't stay running

Tags: docker

Having newbie simpleton issues. I have installed docker toolbox on my Windows 10 64bit machine, I previously updated my virtual box 5.0.12 current.

Trying some simple docker examples from james turnbull's book - but running a deamon ubuntu image just stops running immediately and I don't know why.

I run the docker cli and type the following

```
docker run --name daemon_ubuntu_will  -d ubuntu /bin/sh -c "while true; do 
echo hello world; sleep 1;done"
```

this returns the long id and returns to command prompt  but if I run the

```
docker ps
```

nothing is running and if I run the

```
docker ps -a
```

it shows the container is there but status of stopped.

running  docker inspect daemon_ubuntu_will

```
[
{
    "Id": "57a133f1b3414d1945de0be1d17b4609d774e2602acdfe22b17fe4eacd495458",
    "Created": "2016-01-15T12:19:24.223715466Z",
    "Path": "/bin/bash",
    "Args": [],
    "State": {
        "Status": "exited",
        "Running": false,
        "Paused": false,
        "Restarting": false,
        "OOMKilled": false,
        "Dead": false,
        "Pid": 0,
        "ExitCode": 0,
        "Error": "",
        "StartedAt": "2016-01-15T12:19:24.274741496Z",
        "FinishedAt": "2016-01-15T12:19:24.295086672Z"
    },
    "Image": "c4bea91afef3764163fd506f5c1090be1d34a9b63ece81867cb863455937048e",
    "ResolvConfPath": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/containers/57a133f1b3414d1945de0be1d17b4609d774e2602acdfe22b17fe4eacd495458/resolv.conf",
    "HostnamePath": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/containers/57a133f1b3414d1945de0be1d17b4609d774e2602acdfe22b17fe4eacd495458/hostname",
    "HostsPath": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/containers/57a133f1b3414d1945de0be1d17b4609d774e2602acdfe22b17fe4eacd495458/hosts",
    "LogPath": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/containers/57a133f1b3414d1945de0be1d17b4609d774e2602acdfe22b17fe4eacd495458/57a133f1b3414d1945de0be1d17b4609d774e2602acdfe22b17fe4eacd495458-json.log",
    "Name": "/daemon_ubuntu_will",
    "RestartCount": 0,
    "Driver": "aufs",
    "ExecDriver": "native-0.2",
    "MountLabel": "",
    "ProcessLabel": "",
    "AppArmorProfile": "",
    "ExecIDs": null,
    "HostConfig": {
        "Binds": null,
        "ContainerIDFile": "",
        "LxcConf": [],
        "Memory": 0,
        "MemoryReservation": 0,
        "MemorySwap": 0,
        "KernelMemory": 0,
        "CpuShares": 0,
        "CpuPeriod": 0,
        "CpusetCpus": "",
        "CpusetMems": "",
        "CpuQuota": 0,
        "BlkioWeight": 0,
        "OomKillDisable": false,
        "MemorySwappiness": -1,
        "Privileged": false,
        "PortBindings": {},
        "Links": null,
        "PublishAllPorts": false,
        "Dns": [],
        "DnsOptions": [],
        "DnsSearch": [],
        "ExtraHosts": null,
        "VolumesFrom": null,
        "Devices": [],
        "NetworkMode": "default",
        "IpcMode": "",
        "PidMode": "",
        "UTSMode": "",
        "CapAdd": null,
        "CapDrop": null,
        "GroupAdd": null,
        "RestartPolicy": {
            "Name": "no",
            "MaximumRetryCount": 0
        },
        "SecurityOpt": null,
        "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
        "Ulimits": null,
        "LogConfig": {
            "Type": "json-file",
            "Config": {}
        },
        "CgroupParent": "",
        "ConsoleSize": [
            25,
            155
        ],
        "VolumeDriver": ""
    },
    "GraphDriver": {
        "Name": "aufs",
        "Data": null
    },
    "Mounts": [],
    "Config": {
        "Hostname": "57a133f1b341",
        "Domainname": "",
        "User": "",
        "AttachStdin": false,
        "AttachStdout": false,
        "AttachStderr": false,
        "Tty": false,
        "OpenStdin": false,
        "StdinOnce": false,
        "Env": null,
        "Cmd": [
            "/bin/bash"
        ],
        "Image": "ubuntu",
        "Volumes": null,
        "WorkingDir": "",
        "Entrypoint": null,
        "OnBuild": null,
        "Labels": {},
        "StopSignal": "15"
    },
    "NetworkSettings": {
        "Bridge": "",
        "SandboxID": "",
        "HairpinMode": false,
        "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
        "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "Ports": null,
        "SandboxKey": "",
        "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
        "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
        "EndpointID": "",
        "Gateway": "",
        "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
        "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "IPAddress": "",
        "IPPrefixLen": 0,
        "IPv6Gateway": "",
        "MacAddress": "",
        "Networks": {
            "bridge": {
                "EndpointID": "",
                "Gateway": "",
                "IPAddress": "",
                "IPPrefixLen": 0,
                "IPv6Gateway": "",
                "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                "MacAddress": ""
            }
        }
    }
}
]
```

Why doesn't the daemon server stay up?

I can run an interactive container quite happily using

```
docker run --name mymachine -i -t ubuntu /bin/sh
```

Can any one suggest what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: does "docker logs daemon_ubuntu_will" help ?

Comment: sadly no - it says there is no daemon running

Comment: when you are in the interactive container does "while true; do echo hello world; sleep 1;done" actually work when you run it.

Comment: just had to reboot - i'll check

Comment: yes it does - i did a docker start on previous interactive container, and then did a docker attach my_ubuntu and get the bash prompt.  I then type at the line "while true;do echo hello world; sleep 1; done", and that loops happily to the console until i do the ctrl-c

Comment: i also tried to create a deamon with no command - just started the shell - and that stops instantly as well - i dont think its the script that's causing the problem sadly

Comment: I don't use docker on windows so can only direct you to https://docs.docker.com/windows/step_one/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100776/discussion-between-2fast2bcn-and-william-woodman).

Comment: The output of `docker inspect daemon_ubuntu_will` does not match the command you said that started the container; the `Config.Cmd` should look like this;
 `"Cmd": ["/bin/sh", "-c", "while true; do echo hello world; sleep 1;done"],`